# How to have several column for one label in chart in react?

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-chartjs

I have this JSON data coming from the server and I want to make a bar chart in react with it but because there is only one date for each index of arrays is there any charting library that supports this or any other solutions?

```
results: [{
      date: '1399/1/1',
      remove: {
        done: [6, 6, 1, 6],
        declined: [2, 7, 1, 6]

      },
      add: {
        done: [5, 6, 1, 6],
        declined: [2, 7, 1, 6]

      }
    }, {
      date: '1399/2/1',
      remove: {
        done: [2, 7, 1, 6, 8, 1],
        declined: [2, 7, 1, 6]

      },
      add: {
        done: [5, 9, 1, 6],
        declined: [2, 7, 1, 6, 6]

      }
    }
    ]
```

also, I want to give each bar a custom color based on whether it is done or declined.

Comment: Process this JSON and create new JSON for chart.

Comment: I've tried that but I only have two unique date and charts don't allow me to have several columns for each date.